BigCommerce bulk pricing error with Percent fixed Discount
We are currently having an issue with our BigCommerce store...
The issue specifically: When a customer adds a product with multiple quantities that has a set % discount within 'Bulk pricing' it is currently rounding the price to the fourth decimal (it seems like). Is there a way to limit how many decimals BigCommerce is looking at?
We have not changed anything since November of 2021 -- and just recently all of our products that have multiple quantity discounts (set up in the backend of a product by way of 'bulk pricing') are coming up incorrect with the true value including the fixed % price discount.
We spoke with BigCommerce and they have denied they changed anything that would effect this, and says its on our end but, in the example i am using one of their demo products in a fresh install sandbox and still coming up with the same issues for pricing...


We did try this scenario on a fresh sandbox install of BigCommerce and used one of their demo products and still results with the same wrong pricing. Not sure what else we should do or try for this to spit out the right pricing on the shopping cart. We are currently on Stencil CLI, using bigcommerce out of the box theme and latest versions.
